# How to set html5 property within template.php

Tags: php, jdocument

Apologize for my bad php knowledge, how to set html5 flag for the current document? Something like:

```
 $document->setHtml5(true);
```

This to be executed in template.php where we do not have $document.

My template lacks support for this flag, but in head.php we have:

```
if ($document->isHtml5())
    {
        $buffer .= $tab . '<meta charset="' . $document->getCharset() . '" />' . $lnEnd;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do `JFactory::getDocument();` in most places within Joomla (component, module, plugin, etc) to get the document object.

And then you are correct, it is a call to `setHtml5` like this:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setHtml5(true);
```

This is the function declaration in Joomla's core for reference: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php#L337